# In Steel Beach, who does "Maria" think her father is?

Tags: john-varley

Near the end of *Steel Beach* by John Varley, Maria

> (Hildy)

asks Callie who her father is. She doesn't get an answer, but afterwards, she comments,

> Still, I think I do know. (p. 559)

Who does she think it is? She has mentioned earlier (p. 81) that the king of England is a possible candidate. Is that all she's referring to, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm a little wishy-washy about the [eight-worlds] tag being appropriate for *Steel Beach* as Varley as much as calls it a reboot in the forward, but I think it will be useful eventually.

Comment: @dcmckee - We could either call "Steel Beach" and "The Golden Globe" and, presumably, "Irontown Blues" something like "Eight Worlds Alternate" or just lump it all together. Since there aren't all that many questions on them, I say keep 'em together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're never actually told.

One odd-ball thought that occurred to me was that it could be Walter Editor.

He clearly knows Callie from way back, they both have Heinleiner tendencies, he knows where the surface locks to the Double C Bar ranch are and he takes considerable risks for Maria during the Big Glitch.

Nothing conclusive there, but I think it leaves him in the running.

---

If true it puts an ironic spin on the speculations--early in the book--on where Walter finds his sexual partners.

Comment: I thought of that too. Especially because of the emotion that he shows when he rescues her during the Big Glitch.